# Cassandra: Hector, serializationException invalid stram header

Tags: cassandra, hector

Im currently working with Apache Cassandra (Cassandra version: 1.2.3, Thrift API version: 19.35.0, CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.0.1 (default: 3.0.1)) and Hector 1.0.5.

Im using the following code to insert and retrieve an Object.

```
String cf="User";
key="myKey";
String colName="colName";
String colValue="colvalue";

Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, StringSerializer.get());
mutator.insert(key, cf, HFactory.createStringColumn(colName, colValue));



ColumnQuery<String, String, Object> columnQuery = HFactory.createColumnQuery(
    keyspace,
    StringSerializer.get(),
    StringSerializer.get(),
    ObjectSerializer.get());

    columnQuery.setColumnFamily(cf).setKey(key).setName(colName);
    QueryResult<HColumn<String, Object>> r = columnQuery.execute();

    System.out.println("Read HColumn from cassandra: " + r.get());
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorSerializationException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 636F6C76
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.ObjectSerializer.fromByteBuffer(ObjectSerializer.java:79)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.HColumnImpl.getValue(HColumnImpl.java:124)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.HColumnImpl.toString(HColumnImpl.java:202)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.dargamenteria.tfg.texu.logic.UserDAOImpl.create(UserDAOImpl.java:111)
```

But the following code works, just changed the ObjectSerializer to StringSerializer:

```
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, StringSerializer.get());
mutator.insert(key, cf, HFactory.createStringColumn(colName, colValue));

ColumnQuery<String, String, String> columnQuery = HFactory.createColumnQuery(
    keyspace,
    StringSerializer.get(),
    StringSerializer.get(),
    StringSerializer.get());

    columnQuery.setColumnFamily(cf).setKey(key).setName(colName);
    QueryResult<HColumn<String, String>> r = columnQuery.execute();

    System.out.println("Read HColumn from cassandra: " + r.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into Hector Serializer hierarchy, you will find that ObjectSerializer & StringSerializer  are both siblings, both implementing  Serializer interface and extending AbstractSerializer class.

**fromByteBuffer** method in StringSerializer  is expecting a string, whereas in ObjectSerializer it is expecting an object. And in your code you have defined column value as string type, so you have to use StringSerializer as your set of code is expecting String type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abhi. 
In the first case i define the column value as an Object and the serializer is an ObjectSerializer, and when i try to retrieve the value, i got this exception:"Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorSerializationException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 636F6C76" 

But in the second, column value String and StringSerializer, everything works right. 

And that is what is making me nuts.

Comment: hmmm....at the time of your column family creation, i guess you might have mentioned the Default column value validator as UTF8Type. Can you share the output of **describe CF_NAME** from cassandra-cli

Answer (score 0):

First of all that thanks to Abhi, for its answer :) you gave some important clues.

What i did was inserting ByteBuffers by using the proper serializers.
For example

```
mutator.addInsertion(key, columnFamilyName, 
HFactory.createColumn("name",                   
    ByteBufferSerializer.get().fromByteBuffer(StringSerializer.get().toByteBuffer(uh.getName())), 
    StringSerializer.get(),
    ByteBufferSerializer.get())).

addInsertion(key, columnFamilyName, 
HFactory.createColumn("email",                  
    ByteBufferSerializer.get().fromByteBuffer(ObjectSerializer.get().toByteBuffer(uh.getEmail())), 
    StringSerializer.get(),
    ByteBufferSerializer.get())).
```

And retrieving them for example

```
 StringSerializer.get().fromByteBuffer(
                r.get().getColumnByName("name").getValue())
```

Thank you all!